# boost::locale getting users default locale

Tags: c++, boost

I am trying to use the boost::locale library for an application that will run under different locales.
I noticed the following differences to std::locale

```
std::locale loc("");
```

creates a locale from the users settings. F.e.

```
std::cout.imbue(loc);
double d = 1.25;
std::cout << d;
```

will output 1,25 on my german system, because we use comma as the decimal separator. Not so with the following boost::locale code

```
boost::locale::generator gen;
std::locale loc = gen("");
std::cout.imbue(loc);
double d = 1.25;
std::cout << d;
```

which outputs 1.25.
My question is not so much why there is this difference but how do I create a locale with boost that considers the user settings? I found many examples on how to pass IDs like de-DE etc. to the locale generator but that doesn't help because I need to find the users locale dynamically.

This was tested with VC++2015, boost 1.57 on Windows 10 and I do not use ICU for boost::locale.

Comment: All of boost's examples call `locale::global(loc);` before `.imbue()`, which sounds unnecessary, but what happens for you if you try it?

Comment: I also tried that before but same thing

Comment: What does `loc.name()` return you? Both for the one you create manually, and the one created by Boost?

Comment: OK, this led me to read the documentation again and do more tests. For the manually created locale loc.name() returns an empty string. For boost loc.name() returns * but std::use_facet<boost::locale::info>(loc).name() returns de_DE.UTF-8 ! So the locale seems to be correct, although I would like to know what happens if the system default is english and a user has set german. Regarding the formatting it seems that I always have to apply the stream manipulator boost::locale::as::number to std::cout, otherwise the locale is not considered in formatting floating point values.